# Do I need to bind the secure gateway service to my app?

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I saw the following document.

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SecureGateway/index.html#sg_overview

In the summary near the end, it says "Provision the service and bind it to your app".  But do I really need to bind the secure gateway service to my app? I could access the secure gateway's destination without binding the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.  Since the Secure Gateway service does not actually use VCAP services there are no advantages to binding your application to the service instance.

Answer (score 1):

I [found the same when testing with DB2](http://blog.4loeser.net/2015/05/bluemix-combining-cloud-app-with-my-on.html) and could access the gateway without binding, too.

Binding a service to an app is for the metadata and simplifies administration and deployment. If you delete an app, the related services will also be removed. If you try to delete a service bound to an app, there should be a warning. So what is in the documentation makes sense (at least this time...).